# Starting second AsyncTaskLoader From First One

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

So it seems the following pattern in a class called ActivityClass:

```
private static class AsyncTaskLoader1 extends AsyncTaskLoader<E> {
    ........
}

private static class AsyncTaskLoader2 extends AsyncTaskLoader<F> {
    .........
}

private class LoaderManager1 extends LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<E> {

     private void onLoadFinished(AsyncTaskLoader1 loader, E data) {
           //do stuff with data
           //ok, now we need to start a asynchronous data load based on info we got back from 1st
           ActivityClass.this.getLoaderManager().init(0, null, new LoaderManager2()).forceLoad();
     }

}

private class LoaderManager2 extends LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<D> {
    //...
}
```

This leads to the following runtime exception that looks something like:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: E cannot be cast to F
            at com.mycompany.myapp.ActivityClass$LoaderManager2.onLoadFinished
```

I assume this is because I am calling a second loader from the first one. If this is not possible, I assume there is a way to let the Activity know that data has been loaded so it can start a new AsyncTaskLoader from the UI thread, but I don't know how to do that. Could somebody enlighten me? Thanks.

Comment: Would downvoter care to explain why this is a bad question?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue ended up being that I was passing the same integer ID argument to `initLoader` for both the original call, AND the one in the first `LoadManager`'s `onLoadFinished` method. I assume this was resulting in the result of the first loader to be returned to the wrong manager.